# Wildcard subdomains only working with double slash(//)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wildcard-subdomain

I have created wildcard subdomains based on username. However it is working fine but only issue which occurs it that its working with double slashes at the end. For example **johndoe.example.com//** and if i use **johndoe.example.com/** it redirects me to main domain **example.com**. I am not sure why this is happening and what to i have to do in **.htaccess** file. I tried many things in htaccess but it is not working.

Expected URL - username.example.com

Actual URL - example.com/user/username

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /user/%1 [L]
```

Comment: Well, you will have to add your current configuration, how else do you expect us to help with it?

Comment: @arkascha what configurations do you need ?

Comment: Your rewriting rules mostly. So the content of any host specific configuration files, the standard ones in your http server's host configuration (the relevant bits in there and the distributed ones (often called ".htaccess").

Comment: Please check now, i have updated it.

Comment: Nothing in there that explains your issue. You will have to start debugging. Open a fresh anonymous browser window, open the development console, the network tab in there, make a request (using a single slash) and check the redirections you receive. Best to add the list here too.

Comment: I suspect that you have other redirection rules in place in another configuration.

Comment: There is only one domain and only rewrite that exists is related to wordpress.

Comment: Question is what rewriting rules those domains imply. That depends on your setup, which you did not tell us. If there is only "one domain", the how come your server reacts to those "subdomains"? What takes care of that? And... what is the result of the first debugging step I asked you to do above?